# Dockerfile define multiple ARG arguments in a single line

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Right now I am defining **ARG**s in my Dockerfile like this:

```
ARG CDN_ENDPOINT
ARG AWS_S3_BUCKET
```

Is there a way to define them in a single line similar to **ENV** to avoid creating extra layers in docker image like this:

```
ENV CDN_ENDPOINT=endpoint \
    AWS_S3_BUCKET=bucket
```

Comment: Layers are almost free (if not used wastefully) and I wouldn't worry about this.  (I might try to make those values be set at run time and not build time if it's practical, but that's a different argument.)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**NO, not possible**

After testing this by creating the **ARG**s similar to **ENV** like this:

```
ARG CDN_ENDPOINT \
    AWS_S3_BUCKET
```

I got this error:

```
ARG requires exactly one argument definition
```

So judging from that, the ARG command only allows one argument. So its impossible to define multiple **ARG**s in a single line inside dockerfile.

Answer (score 16):

On a different note, ARG does not go in the build image. So may be, one should not worry about the layers caused by ARG.

Answer (score 7):

To achieve what you want you have to do this:

in your Dockerfile define the ARG variables you need with a default value (so, in case you don't pass it it can still work):

```
ARG P_TAG=8-jdk
FROM openjdk:${P_TAG}

ARG P_VERSION="1.22.2-stable"

ENV TAG=${P_TAG}
ENV VERSION=${P_VERSION}

RUN echo TAG=${TAG}
RUN echo VERSION=${VERSION}
```

Then your build line should go like this:

```
docker build --build-arg P_TAG=11-jdk --build-arg P_VERSION=2.0.4-stable
```

You need to be sure that your dockerfile contains as ARG all the variables you need to pass.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to write a one-liner, but it seems to require specifying default values, like so:

```
ARG CDN_ENDPOINT=endpoint \
    AWS_S3_BUCKET=bucket
```

One could then override these values by specifying build arguments in the docker build command:

```
docker build -t <name:tag> --build-arg CDN_ENDPOINT=overriddenValue1 --build-arg AWS_S3_BUCKET=overriddenValue2 <context>
```

To test layering, I created two Dockerfiles:

**Dockerfile-1:**

```
FROM alpine

ARG CDN_ENDPOINT=endpoint \
    AWS_S3_BUCKET=bucket
```

**Dockerfile-2:**

```
FROM alpine

ARG CDN_ENDPOINT=endpoint
ARG AWS_S3_BUCKET=bucket
```

After building each and running the command `docker history <image-id>`, here were the results showing the layers. It does seems like **image-1** kept the ARG one-liner to one layer while **image-2** used two layers:

**image-1:**

```
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
ca690c8c2cfc   3 months ago   ARG CDN_ENDPOINT=endpoint AWS_S3_BUCKET=buck…   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2a949686d9886ac7c…   5.54MB
```

**image-2:**

```
IMAGE          CREATED        CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
e4bee80eb809   3 months ago   ARG AWS_S3_BUCKET=bucket                        0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   ARG CDN_ENDPOINT=endpoint                       0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
<missing>      3 months ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:2a949686d9886ac7c…   5.54MB
```

Comment: Indeed. But unfortunately this is not documented (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing previous answers with a possible outcome for ARG instruction:

If for some reason you pretend to reuse those ARGs after FROM action, you can also use a single line and without need to re-declare default value.

```
ARG PARENT_IMAGE=rocky8
ARG PARENT_TAG=8.9
ARG REGISTRY=docker.io
FROM ${REGISTRY}${PARENT_IMAGE}:${PARENT_TAG}

ARG PARENT_IMAGE PARENT_TAG

#e.g. for a ARG re-usage, declaring a label:
LABEL org.baseimage="${PARENT_IMAGE}:${PARENT_VERSION}"
```

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34129#issuecomment-445540809